# set virtualhost in apache is not direct to my goal directory of laravel project

Tags: laravel, apache

OS: Microsoft Windows 10

backend framework: Laravel

my goal: when I access to "http://example.domain", it can direct to laravel index.php.

httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:\Apache24\htdocs\NKUST_foodpanda\public"
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    ServerName example.domain
    ErrorLog "C:\Apache24\logs\error.log"
    CustomLog "C:\Apache24\logs\access.log" combined
    <Directory "C:\Apache24\htdocs\NKUST_foodpanda\public"> 
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I save httpd-vhosts.conf and restart my apache, and now, when I access to "http://example.domain", it will direct to "C:\Apache24\htdocs", not "C:\Apache24\htdocs\NKUST_foodpanda\public".

Answer (score 0):

I have tried with same possible scenario as yours with following entry httpd-vhost.conf. Checked it with both '' and '/' and it is working for me. Make sure to provide proper permission to your directories. If this could not work you need to provide more info.

```
    <VirtualHost example.domain:80>
      DocumentRoot "C:\Apache24\htdocs\NKUST_foodpanda\public"
      DirectoryIndex index.html
      ServerName example.domain
      ErrorLog "C:\Apache24\logs\error.log"
      CustomLog "C:\Apache24\logs\access.log" combined
      <Directory "C:\Apache24\htdocs\NKUST_foodpanda\public"> 
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
      </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Always explain your answer, don't just say "try this".  Explain what you've changed, and why so people can learn from it. You are missing the closing tag for VirtualHost.

Comment: is it different from my setup?

Comment: @GertB. Thank you i will make sure that and VirtualHost closing tag had been there but for some reason it is not showing on new line. I have edited my answer.

Comment: @hua please check edited answer

Comment: @BRIJESHDAVE I tried. but it's doesn't work, too. I think it is not main problem beacuse I use "\" in my other computer and it work successful.

Comment: If it was to check if forward slash was better than backward slash, you should have commented instead of answered. I really don't think that will solve the problem.

Comment: @hua i have tested first and edited my answer. Please check if it could help.

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work, too. why should I set domain name in virturalhost tag, not "*"?

Comment: because in my dev setup i have multiple sites for testing so need to specify specific domain for that entry.

Comment: Now in your case you need to provide more info for your apache config, version and os details if you need more help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set a newer setup in "httpd-vhosts.conf", you have to delete comment out "Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf" in "httpd.conf".

I have not notice this problem, I comment out "Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf" and set something in "httpd-vhosts.conf" at the same time, so "httpd-vhosts.conf" doesn't work.